# Using Ruby, can I access the Return variable in the method before it is returned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on developing a Ruby application and am using puts and otherwise to display variables within methods to trace what is going on.  Well, that was changing the "return" of the method, of course.  Is there a generalized Ruby variable that allows me to access the current return variable within the method prior to terminating that method?  That way, I could access it in puts and then make sure it is set again prior to terminating.  I do understand that the last result of the method is what is passed forward.  I am specifically looking for a generalized way of accessing that variable whatever it may be in whatever method I am debugging.

I am using Rubymine as my IDE and I do use it for debugging.  But, there is something about REPL's like IRB that are just interesting.  It's probably the 360 assembler programmer in me, but I am dating myself.  How many of you first programmed in 1969?  LOL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option might be the `.tap` method. Assuming you had

```
x = foo
```

and wanted to know what the return value of `foo` was from the outside:

```
x = foo.tap { |r| puts r.inspect }
```

Remainder of `puts r.inspect` are written `p r`, which is valid shorthand syntax for same thing (and by the way, `p` returns its parameter so you could just literally stick a `p` in front of returned variables in many cases - a few syntax niceties excepted)

Alternatively, if you want to check inside of `foo`, and the definition is like this:

```
def foo
  # Do stuff
  something_that_is_returned
end
```

You can add the `.tap` onto the last statement without affecting the returned value:

```
def foo
  # Do stuff
  something_that_is_returned.tap { |r| p r }
end
```

This works because `.tap` yields the current object to the block, and returns the original object regardless of the return value of the block. It's quite useful to insert a `.tap` into a long chain of methods to inspect a middle result.

E.g. You have

```
x = foo.map {|x| whatever}.select {|x| whatever}
```

and want to know what `select` is receiving without re-writing lots of code:

```
x = foo.map {|x| whatever}.tap { |r| p r }.select {|x| whatever}
```

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you may wish to define a global method for it:

```
def tapp
  tap do |o|
    p o
  end
end
```

To use, just append `.tapp` to an expression:

```
something_that_is_returned.tapp
```

Comment: Just to be clear to R_V, to use this, you would just "add" `.tap { |r| p r }` to the end of all statements that would be "returned", and the return chain will be uninterrupted

Comment: Very, very informative.  I guess I am wondering how tap differs from each then.  I mean, map returns the result.  Each returns the original object.  Is that what tap does?  Or, is tap more generalized?

Comment: @R_G: `.tap` is quite similar to `.each`, the main difference is that `.tap` always runs the block once, passing in the original object (whilst `.each` of course runs block multiple times against contents of the object). `.tap` is also available on the general base class `Object`, whilst `.each` is only available on container classes. So `.tap` is even available on `nil`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you want to be a little more expressive, you could define a method

```
def puts_and_return(r)
    puts r
    r
end
```

and then use

```
puts_and_return (last statement of method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why a simple puts does not work for you?

```
def foo
  bar = 1
  puts bar
  bar
end
```

Comment: Yes, that works.  However, my question is more generalized.  Is there something that I can copy and paste to put the variable and then set it again without consideration of the variable name in any and every method without consideration of what variable the method used or how it was set?  In particular, some methods don't terminate in a simple direct assignment any way.